# $\varphi(5^n - 1) = 5^m -1$ implies $\gcd(n, m) > 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I'm thinking about a problem 2 from http://math.mosolymp.ru/upload/files/2020/khamovniki/11/S3_t4_final.pdf

> Let $n$, $m$ be natural numbers such that $\varphi(5^n - 1) = 5^m - 1$. Prove that $n$ and $m$ are not coprime.

What I did so far: by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1), we want to prove that $\gcd(5^n-1, 5^m-1)>4$.
So, if $8 | 5^n - 1$, we are done, because each odd prime $p$ in the decomposition of $5^n-1$ spits out a $2$ in the decomposition of $\varphi(5^n - 1)$, so either $5^n-1=8$ (which it isn't) or $8|\varphi(5^n-1)$.

Also $5^n-1$ cannot be divided by a square of an odd prime.

So, the following is true: $5^n-1 = 4 p_1 \cdot ... \cdot p_t$ and $5^m - 1= 2 (p_1-1)...(p_t-1)$.

Some other remarks:

It is known and easy to prove that $k |\varphi(a^k-1) $ for every $k$, so $n |5^m-1$

Also, by LTE lemma, $m$ is even and so $n$ is odd. (And, I think, $m$ must be divisible by some huge power of 2, since ratio of $5^n-1$ to $5^m-1$ should be greater than $5$ and the product $\prod \frac{p}{p-1}$ diverges very slowly)

All that doesn't allow me to solve the problem. What am I missing here?

Comment: What makes you think this is true? Do you have any examples of this phenomenon occurring? If so, it might help you visualize why it is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a tricky exercise in the famous *Problems from the book* by Titu Andreescu (Quadratic Reciprocity chapter). This was a previous Taiwanese TST problem and you can certainly expect it to be hard. Anyway i remember seeing the solution from the following link.

- https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=325&lmm=0 $\textbf{Question 20.}$

Hope this helps.